# Input data formatting problem for an array in a model

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to work with a function (Log Periodic Power Law) and the input prices in the code example show like this:

[Price input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF9rm.png)

however when I try to import the data I have, be it csv or txt it has problems. Actually I'm guessing *that's* the problem because the rest is pretty much the same.

The code is taken almost exactly as it appears in the pypi.org page
(https://pypi.org/project/lppls/):

```
data = data_loader.sp500()
time = np.linspace(0, len(data)-1, len(data))
price = np.log(data['Adj Close'].values)
# create Mx2 matrix (expected format for LPPLS observations)
observations = np.array([time, price])
MAX_SEARCHES = 25
lppls_model = lppls.LPPLS(observations=observations)
tc, m, w, a, b, c, c1, c2 = lppls_model.fit(observations, MAX_SEARCHES, minimizer='Nelder-Mead')
# visualize the fit
lppls_model.plot_fit()
```

The only change was the data I imported and it keeps saying "IndexError: too many indices for array".

This was my code:

```
retdji = pd.read_csv('mdji.csv')
content = np.array(retdji.transpose())
observations = np.array([time, content])
MAX_SEARCHES = 25
lppls_model = lppls.LPPLS(observations=observations)
# fit the model to the data and get back the params
tc,m,w,a,b,c,c1,c2 = lppls_model.fit(observations, MAX_SEARCHES, minimizer='Nelder-Mead')
# visualize the fit
lppls_model.plot_fit()
```

So, if I have my data in that format how should I manipulate it so it can be accepted by the model?
Thanks in advance.

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZXnY.png)

Comment: Try checking the shapes of `price` and `content`.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel sorry what does mean when the array shows with a blank space? I checked content and is (4558, 1) and price (1258,)... why is it like that? and it's there a way to get rid of the 1? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just need to make the shapes of `price` and `content` equal, `content.flatten()` would do it for you. But it doesn't make sense that you're passing something of the order `10^-3` in place of `10`.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel Yeah I tried with both flatten and squeeze, now the problems seems to be that I have an object type array and the functions is not taking it. The output of content is like `array(['-0.0075',...,dtype=object)` while the price one is `array([7.4749,...)` sorry do you know how can I feed this data correctly into the model? I tried `np.bmat` and other things but I wonder if there is a less complicated way because I ended up with a U22 type

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that's `str`, you can directly do `np.array(list(map(lambda x: float(x), content.flatten())))` on your original `content`

Comment: @YashvanderBamel that solved the problem! Thank you so much, I'll definitely learn more about data types and lists to handle them better. Again, thank you!!